# .NET: Why isn't side by side assembly versioning magic? Upgrade Newtonsoft_json is a huge project... why?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

This is a product manager question. I am not a guru in Visual Studio, but I am intimate with win32, and reasonably intimate w .NET.

The question: Why, when one library requires a newer Newtonsoft_json, do we have to go and tweak every lib and project to migrate the entire solution (which is sthing like 110 projects and 60+ third party libs) to the new Newtonsoft_json?

(Not every proj or lib uses this json lib, but certainly 40 or more do.)

We have to tweak and recompile all kinds of stuff, including sdks from many third parties.

I thought that .NET would magically load the right lib, and we could have mult vers of the json lib side by side.

Instead, we have a massive checkin (and days of testing) of mods similar to the one pictured below.

Yes, we know there is such a thing as the GAC, and no, we never use it, because it makes installation/deployment a nightmare.

What is the hidden knowledge we are missing? I thought (naively, it appears) that .NET had a few paths to solve dll hell. Am I mistaken?

[image]

Comment: It does magically load the right version.  If it can find it.  But it can't find it, NewtonSoft.Json is notorious for not deploying to the GAC.  So when you build the solution, one version is going to overwrite the DLL of the other version.  And one library will get the wrong version.  Standard DLL Hell.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks! OP enhanced to disc GAC. I thought .NET had some practical solves for dll hell.... (I know _all_ about dll hell)